# Unable to acquire image through ImageIO.read(url) because of connection timed out

Tags: java, url, timeout, connection, javax.imageio

The following code always seems to fail:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/8636005.jpg");
    Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
    System.out.println(img);
```

I've checked the url, and it is a valid jpg image. The error I get is:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
>           at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1385)
>           at maestro.Main2.main(Main2.java:25)
>
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:310)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:176)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:163)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
>           at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:174)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:240)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
>           at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:338)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:814)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:755)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:680)
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1005)
>           at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1029)
>           at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1383)
>           ... 1 more
>
> Java Result: 1

What does this mean?
Funny thing is, if I change my internet-connection to that of the neighbour's wireless, it suddenly works.

Comment: DNS issues? What if you use the IP 92.122.126.242 instead in the address?

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me. :)

```
URL url = new URL("http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/8636005.jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
System.out.println(image);
```

I know I am late. Since, even I faced the same issue, thought of putting as it would help some one. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe unlikely on a home network, but a lot of companies have HTTP proxy servers that can make your errors a little misleading.  Often the URL will appear to work fine manually because your browser is configured to use your proxy server.  You can set the proxy settings on the command line or in the code, see: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html.

Comment: But what settings should I use for the proxy?

Comment: That, I couldn't say.  You could check your browser's proxy settings and copy those?

Comment: firefox does not list any proxy. When I enter about:config, the properties network.proxy.ftp = "" and network.proxy.http = "". Meaning they are not set (and thus not used)

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfect for me.

If you have a very slow internet-connection, then that is the reason. Or you are downloading/uploading stuff (http, torrents, ftp, ...)

> I've manually checked the url, and it is valid, and contains a valid jpg image.

### Edit:

Did you tested it in a browser? <del>If so, maybe it's timeout is longer.</del>
Did you tested it on your ***own*** network with the browser?

> What does this mean?

A time out exception means that you couldn't create a Socket. This can have a few reasons:

- Server is not responding.

  - The server is very busy.
- The packages are lost. This can have also a few reasons:

  - Your are downloading and your broadband is full.
  - You are far away from the internet-provider's "central". (You live in the country)

Comment: Have tried using a URLConnection (so that I can set the timeout). And set the timeout to a minute. Still nothing.

Comment: Also, I have a adsl internet-connection, enabling high-speed downloads. So that can't be it. If the server is busy, then I wouldn't be able to fetch the image-url in the first place. Haven't used up all my download-capacity, downloading various large torrents as we speak. I live near a large city.