# Getting 403 when trying to get StackOverflow's flair image with ImageIO

Tags: java

I have written following code in my program

```
url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/3626698.png?theme=dark");
ImageIO.read(url);
```

I am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1395)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/3626698.png?theme=dark
....
```

I can get an image using `wget`, by writing url on browser etc...
I don't understand why I am getting 403 here.

Comment: look in to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023243/unable-to-acquire-image-through-imageio-readurl-because-of-connection-timed-ou may be it will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it may possible server at this url checks for property like user agent,so you are getting 403 error,

> note : in this case its working by just setting blank User-Agent
>   property

Try this code

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/3626698.png?theme=dark");
  HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
  httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", ""); 
  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(httpcon.getInputStream());
  File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
  ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);   
 } 
 catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Well, I am honest person and didn't wanted to lie server that I am Mozilla, not java application. ;)

Comment: just left that property blank , it will also work in this case :)

Comment: Yeah, it is also working, You just saved me from being a lier. BTY It is strange that server is giving me error because I didn't provided a header, and is not giving any if I just provide header with blank value.